# Style individual Picker.Item in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, picker

Is there any way to style individual Picker.Items? Other than the text color?

Also, somewhat related, What props will a Picker.Item take?
I know they'll take "key", "value", "label" and "color". But are there any others?

I'm trying to style one of the Picker.Item's in my Picker component a different way than the rest of the Picker.Items in that Picker.

Specifically I'm trying to modify the fontWeight, but I haven't been able to change any of the styling except for the color of the text with that color property.

I know you can use itemStyle as a prop for the Picker component to style all of the items, but what if you want one of them to look a little different than the others? Is there a way to do that?

```
<Picker
  style={{height: 130, width: 130}}
  selectedValue={this.state.day}
  itemStyle={{height: 130, fontFamily: 'Rubik-Regular'}}
  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({day: itemValue})}
>
  <Picker.Item label="Day" value={-1} color='red'/>
  { validDays.map((i) => ( <Picker.Item key={i} label={i.toString()} value={i} /> )) }
</Picker>
```

Trying to change what that first Picker.Item (label="Day") looks like.
I tried messing with style prop with no success:

```
<Picker.Item label="Day" value={-1} style={{ color: 'red'}}/>
```

Also tried messing with giving label a Text component like this:

```
<Picker.Item label={(<Text>Hello</Text>)} value={-1}/>
```

That wouldn't render at all. Threw an error.

Also tried:

```
<Picker.Item label="" value={-1} color='red'><Text>Hello</Text></Picker.Item>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only props that you can use for the `Picker.Item` are mentioned here in [**Picker.ios.js**](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/57919a3edd3d09f595224e0d92f95da1df75e884/Libraries/Components/Picker/PickerIOS.ios.js#L102) and [**PickerAndroid.android.js**](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/57919a3edd3d09f595224e0d92f95da1df75e884/Libraries/Components/Picker/PickerAndroid.android.js#L78)

```
static propTypes = {
    value: PropTypes.any, // string or integer basically
    label: PropTypes.string,
    color: PropTypes.string,
  };
```

Therefore you cannot supply any other values to it.